# React Native FlatList's scrollToEnd() does not work

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native

I want to make a floating action button to scroll my FlatList to bottom automatically. My FlatList component described as below:

```
<FlatList
  ref={(ref) => { this.flatListRef = ref; }}
  contentContainerStyle={this.state.barangFiltered.length === 0 && { paddingTop: 10, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}
  showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
  data={this.state.barangFiltered}
  keyExtractor={(item, index) => `barang-${index}`}
  renderItem={({ item, index }) => <Barang
    item={item}
    index={index}
    navigation={this.props.navigation}
    duplicateBarang={(item) => this._duplicateBarang(item)}
    deleteBarang={(item) => this._deleteBarang(item)}
  />}
  ListEmptyComponent={<Text style={{ fontSize: 16, fontWeight: '400' }}>List is empty</Text>}
  getItemLayout={(data, index) => { return {length: 200, index, offset: 200 * index} }}
/>
```

And the button component:

```
<TouchableOpacity
  activeOpacity={0.7}
  style={styles.fab}
  onPress={() => this.flatListRef.scrollToEnd()}
>
  <Ionicons name="ios-add" size={32} color="#0035C9" />
</TouchableOpacity>
```

But, whenever I press the button, it does nothing without produce any error returned. What's going wrong here?

Answer (score 5):

For those who are still looking for a solution, `scrollToEnd()` is not working because it is triggered before the change is made to the `FlatList`.
Since it inherits from `ScrollView` the best way here is to call `scrollToEnd()` in `onContentSizeChange` like so :

`<FlatList
            ref = "flatList"
            onContentSizeChange={()=> this.refs.flatList.scrollToEnd()} />`

Comment: To help make this answer more useful, could you share relevant parts here instead of just a link? Link only answers aren't very helpful.

Comment: I just wanted to avoid repeating the same answer but to let it be more useful as you requested this is my solution:
`<FlatList
            ref = "flatList"
            onContentSizeChange={()=> this.refs.flatList.scrollToEnd()} /> `

Comment: You basically need to call `scrollToEnd()`in `onContentSizeChange` which is a `ScrollView` function inherited by `Flatist` and triggered when the data changes.

Answer (score 1):

A small refine in your code might help.

```
Class Parent extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return(
            <React.Fragment>
                <Flatlist />                 // Your flatlist
                <TouchableOpacity />         // Your FAB 
            </React.Fragment>
        );
    }
}
```

Sometimes your view get overlapped by another view so you cannot perform clicking action.
Also give proper positioning as per your design and **zIndex** to the **FAB(floating action button)**

Comment: My whole screen structure looks like this: https://pastebin.com/dn764X68 @kosalram-rama-krishnan

Comment: I tested with alert action to onPress() and it works. It seems not the clicking action problem.

Comment: Hey @JustinusHermawan you are wrapping a flatlist inside a scroll view which I think unnecessary.
Also I'm insisting the same thing again.
Your Flatlist and Button need to be siblings of particular parent.
`<ScrollView>
    <Flatlist />
    <TouchableOpacity />
</ScrollView>`

Comment: Yes, you're right, I just solved it by removing the unnecessary ScrollView. So, they are now siblings.

Answer (score 0):

It was solved by removing my ScrollView wrapper of the FlatList component. So, both FLatList and FAB components are in the same parent.